# Performance of returning View in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have very simple controller and no data in database, but for some reason my application needs 1300ms to return View after clicking on link

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(User.Identity.Name);

    if (user == null || user?.Permissions != Permissions.Student)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = $"Unauthorized";
        return View();
    }

    var user_friends = _context.Users.Where(x => x.FriendList.Any(x => x.Id == user.Id).ToList();

    var list = user_friends.Select(x => Mapper(x)).ToList();

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("time:");
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // it takes 240 ms

    return View(list);
    //   Request finished in 1327.6186ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
}
```

---

```
public ObjectDTO Mapper(Object input)
{
    return new ObjectDTO
    {
        FirstName = input.FirstName,
        SecondName = input.SecondName,
        Age = input.Age,
        School = input.School,
        Email = input.Email
    }
}
```

Additionally I've overwritten

> public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)

With another db call + some logic, which's another 200ms

So, let's round it and those 2 controller methods toghether take 240+200, so let's say 600ms

Where did those additional 700 (1300-600) ms come from?

How can I measure time that View render actually takes?

Can a few string comparisions in .cshtml file affect it that hard?

Comment: Don't do stuff like `Console.WriteLine` use the in built logging system. Output to console is sync and when a lot of stuff writes in there, things are getting slow

Comment: Something is not right, 200ms for your action alone seems high. Look into https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/AspDotNetCore

Comment: Is it on production? `ToList()` is a blocking code so if you have a lot of requests, its not going to efficiently use your threads. Also we dont know what you do in your view and how **big** your result is? 10 records? 100? 100000 ? a million? HTML Views and html render engines are not made for render megabytes worth of html code, on big data you need pagination etc.

Comment: @Tseng the thing is, this table in database is empty! I'm returning 0 or sometimes 1 record(s)

Comment: I just used miniprofiler and it says that my requests take that much time, ehh... Apparently I gotta rewrite smth

Comment: At least post your view code (partial or complete if its not too big). Also try to provider a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Tseng I've found bottleneck! :D I've been using MSSQL Express locally, but my PC lacked of RAM. When I switched to DB that was running on server which had enough resources it started working fine. From 1600ms to 200~